# Не работает перенос строки в PHP

Tags: php, css

Вставляю переменную, содержащую текст с символами переноса строки `\r\n` (просто `\n`) (пробовал `<br/>`) с помощью шаблонизатора LightnCandy в блок `div` — в результате переносы не работают. Подскажите как решить проблему.

Comment: Код покажите, который не работает так, как ожидается.

Comment: на выходе в html что получается? не выходит так что он при выводе экранирует тэги (хз что за шаблонизатор такой)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на div надо добавить стиль `white-space:pre` или `white-space:pre-line` Вопрос к не php а к css относится

Comment: Так автор же говорит, что и `<br>` использовал,.. так что, возможно, там дело скорее в том «чудном» шаблонизаторе.

Comment: подождем тогда что скажет - аффтар в студио :-) стиль ему 3 минуты проверить

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил white-space:pre к div и заработали \r\n

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй с пробелом (html5) `<br />`;

Попробуй без пробела `<br>`;

В php рабочий пример `echo '<a>Привет</a><br />'`;